# While Loops (And, Not, Or)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I need help with this simple question. I'm starting to learn more about while loops and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

There are 3 criteria:

1) The string must start with "b" or "B"

2) The string must have 6 characters

3) The last letter of the string must be "z" or "Z"

It will print "Error" and prompt the user again if any of the conditions are not met. It will print "Nice!" if it meets the criteria.

This is my code:

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")
length = len(string)

while (not(string[0] == "b" or string[0] == "B" or string[length-1] == "z" or string[length-1] == "Z" and length < 6)):
    print("Error!")
    string = input("Enter a string: ")    
print("Nice! ")
```

If I enter "1000", the output will be "Error!"
If I enter "bz", the output will be "Nice!". It should print the error message as the length is less than 6.

Comment: It sounds like you need regular expressions.

Comment: You don't update `length` after entering more than one string.

Comment: None of the answers good enough to accept?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as simple as using `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` to test the boundary characters:

```
s = input("Enter a string: ") 
while True:
    if len(s) == 6 and s.startswith(('b', 'B')) and s.endswith(('z', 'Z')):
        print('Nice')
        break
    else:
        print('Error, try again!')
        s = input("Enter a string: ")
```

The length is checked first so that the conditionals short-circuit once the `len` expression  (an *O(* 1 *)* operation) fails.

Comment: TIL `startswith` and `endswith` can accept a tuple of test strings

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
    string = input("Enter a string: ")
    length = len(string)
    while (not(string[0] == "b" or string[0] == "B" or string[length-1] == "z" 
    or string[length-1] == "Z" and length < 6)):
    print("Error!")
    string = input("Enter a string: ")    
    print("Nice! ")
```

to

```
    string = input("Enter a string: ")
    length = len(string)
    while (not( (string[0] == "b" or string[0] == "B") and (string[length-1] 
     == "z" or string[length-1] == "Z") and (length == 6))):
          print("Error!")
          string = input("Enter a string: ")    
    print("Nice! ")
```

Comment: This still isn't right.  If the string begins with 'b' it ignores when it ends with, and if it ends with 'z' it ignores what it begins with.  It's the same problem OP

Comment: Isn't it the same? #@interntseekho

Comment: no "and" means both of the condition must be true and "or" mean if just one qualifies its OK just make all of them or and check it not working the switch it to "and" and check

Comment: just change "and length < 6)" to "or length < 6)"

Comment: I still don't get the error message although I changed it to "OR"

Comment: Now try changing them all to "and"

Comment: @interntseekho regardless of what I type, it will give me the Error message when I changed them all to "and"

Comment: let me try it by my self and i will send you a solution soon enough

Comment: i have checked the below code now it works perfectly

        string = input("Enter a string: ")
        length = len(string)
        while (not( (string[0] == "b" or string[0] == "B") and (string[length-1] == 
         "z" or string[length-1] == "Z") and (length == 6))):
                  print("Error!")
                  string = input("Enter a string: ")    
        print("Nice! ")

Comment: just change the while statement to 
while (not( (string[0] == "b" or string[0] == "B") and (string[length-1] == "z" or string[length-1] == "Z") and (length == 6))):
also indent the statements you want to use inside while and don't indent the print nice statement

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important python idioms is to keep your code easily readable. This helps yourself to spot mistakes very fast and other people can understand your code without a lot of effort. Therefore I suggest to code your problem as follows:

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")

def conditions_satisfied(string):
    cond1 = string[0] == "b" or string[0] == "B"
    cond2 = string[-1] == "z" or string[-1] == "Z"
    cond3 = len(string) == 6
    return cond1 and cond2 and cond3

while (not conditions_satisfied(string)):
    print("Error!")
    string = input("Enter a string: ")
print("Nice! ")
```

prints:

```
Enter a string: 1000
Error!
Enter a string: bz
Error!
Enter a string: b1234z
Nice!
```

As already mentioned:

- you don't update lengh inside the while loop
- you say the string length has to equal 6 but you write the condition "it has to be smaller than 6": `<6`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the condition (looks more readable to me):

```
string = input("Enter a string:")

while string[0] not in ["b", "B"] or string[-1] not in ["z", "Z"] or len(string) != 6:
    print("Error!")
    string = input("Enter a string:")
print("Nice!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string = input("Enter a string: ")
length = len(string)

if length == 8:
    if (re.match(r'(b|B).*.(z|Z)$', string)):
        print("Nice! ")
    else:
        print("Error!")
```